# XML Child node attribute

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve attributes for parent and child nodes. I tried to use the example 
[showed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833281/xml-child-node-attribute-value) but it is giving me "can't be applied to given type".

```
static class Entry {
   final String ED,Home, Shift, Detail;
   Entry(String ED,String Home, String Shift,String Detail) {
      this.ED= ED;
      this.Home = Home;
      this.Shift = Shift;
      this.Detail = Detail;
      Node entryNode = entriesNodeList.item(i);
      entries.add(new Entry(
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/@name"),  
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/@starDate"),
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/@endDate"), 
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/Shift/@employeeID"),
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/Shift/@start"),
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/Shift/@end"), 
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/Shift/Detail/@start"), 
         evalString(entryNode, "Home/Shift/Detail/@end")
```

XML FILE:

```
`<ED CS="BLUE" Timestamp="2011-03-23 13:57:01" xmlns:js="TEST/js">
 <Home name="57511" startDate="2011-03-12" endDate="2011-03-18">
 <Shift ID="1170108" start="2011-03-12 0718" end="2011-03-12 1636" >
 <Detail type="Meal" start="2011-03-12 1218" end="2011-03-12 1248" /> 
 </Shift>
 </ED>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for the class "Entry" only takes 4 String arguments and you are trying to call it with. The Class also only seems to hold 4 fields. Maybe you'd want to actually introduce complex Classes for ED (with the fields CS, Timestamp, Home and Shift), Home, Shift and Detail which would represent your xml file as a Java object hierarchy.

Comment: Patrick - that makes sense, when I commented out the four extra lines from the evaluate string section I get a result. I will research on the complex classes as you suggested.

Comment: I updated the consractor and the class "Entry" to accept 8 fields. Now it returns all 8 expected values. But it only returns one line (the file has several lines). This line only returns one line.      for (Entry entry : entries) { System.out.println(entry); }